Python returning me a ModuleNotFoundError despite correctly importing the module
Right, I have a module called uniqueid.py in my media app.
I also have the standard models file, in the same media app file.
# models.py

import....
import...
import uniqueid

class NewsArticle(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=10, default=uniqueid.media_article_id, editable=False)

In my uniqueid.py file, I have the following:
# uniqueid.py
import random
import string

def media_article_id():
    random_string= ''.join(random.choices(string.digits, k=8))  # Generates a random string
    return f"{random_string}"


What is the reason behind the fact that Python is not seeing the uniqueid.py module? Why am I constantly getting the following, despite correctly importing the module?
  File "C:\Users\xxx\OneDrive - xxx\xxxx\media\models.py", line 3, in <module>
    import uniqueid
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'uniqueid'


from .uniqueid import media_article_id.

Yup, makes no difference.

If you have a project then the import starts from the initial directory of the project so you need to add the directories leading to your media app file in your django models file.(I assume you use django.) Also try using ´as´ when ikmporting stuff. For example import media.uniqueid  as uid.
This usualy solves similar problems for me.

I know how to import modules, I have been going it this way for years, and now all of a sudden its decided it doesn't want to know. It makes absolutely no sense.

It could also happen because of a forgotten commit. Did you commit the uniqueid.py file to your repository? In my experience django can also have problems with uncommited modules.

I think you're not telling django from where to import uniqueid.
If it's in the same file, do this:
from . import uniqueid

the "." symbolizes the current directory you're in.
Also dont forget to make migrations.

Yep, I tried that as well, it bitches about that too. All Django does is moan.

did you try to give django abspath?

I've figured the answer. Don't to it. Use UUID instead. Start by importing the UUID built-in python module by import uuid.
Thanks for all your input.
